# Getting Logs of Console in Variable in TCL

Tags: bash, tcl

Is it possible to get logs generated by one function in variable without returning that value from that function in TCL like what `"$"` used to be do in BASH.

```
function f1 {
    echo "ABC"
    return 0
}
```

Calling procedure is,

```
var=$(f1) ;# gives output ABC
```

What i know about how to solve this problem is,

```
proc f1 {} {
    return "ABC | 0"
}
```

At the time of calling i need extract both value like,

```
set console_msg [lindex [split [f1] "|"] 0]
set retval [lindex [split [f1] "|"] 1]
```

Is there a proper way to do it in TCL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This may seem obvious to you in hindsight:

```
set value [f1]
```

and to assign to variables:

```
lassign [split $value |] msg val
```

Comment: let me rephrase it properly. what `$` do in bash. can take ABC value without returing in TCL?

Comment: Then, no. If you want to return 2 things from a proc, return a list of 2 elements. `proc f1 {} {set x "message"; set y 42; return [list $x $y]}` then `lassign [f1] msg retval`

Comment: Got the another way how to return multiple value using `lassign` other that what i was doing using `split`. But still there is no BASH `$` replacement in TCL. cause we were not returning ABC in BASH but still we can get using `$`.. PS: i am not comparing two languages. but that's what my need is

Comment: You are not quite precise in your terminology. "bash $" is really `$() `-- command substitution. Tcl does have that in `exec`. However in bash, calling am external command and calling a shell function is the same mechanism but it's different in Tcl. You can capture the output of an external command or the return value of a proc.